# Upserting documents in elasticsearch using multiple fields instead of one

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Further to question [Upsert documents in Elasticsearch using custom ID field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672862/upsert-documents-in-elasticsearch-using-custom-id-field), now I need to upsert the documents with 2+ fields from the input.

Taking the same example as the above question -

Sample data:

`TABLE="TRADE"|TradeID="1234"|Qty=100|Price=100.00|BuyOrSell="BUY"|Stock="ABCD Inc."`

if we receive modification on the above record:

`TABLE="TRADE"|TradeID="1234"|Qty=120|Price=101.74|BuyOrSell="BUY"|Stock="ABCD Inc."`

I need to upsert based on TradeID and Stock both. I could not find any documentation on-site mentioning it. I could actually create a new field that is the concatenation of two fields but I want to avoid it.

Comment: it's the same problem, you simply need to create a compound ID with `TradeID` and `Stock` and then update the document that has that ID

Comment: @Val - Would you please elaborate on how to create that compound ID ? Is there something that I add in the output as below -
`action => "update"
document_id => "%{TradeID} %{Stock}"
doc_as_upsert => true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a compound ID with `TradeID` and `Stock`, something like

```
`document_id => "%{TradeID}-%{Stock}"`
```

It would be better to use a stock ticker instead of the stock name, though.

Another way is to use the [`fingerprint` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.17/plugins-filters-fingerprint.html) to create a consistent hash out of the `TradeID` and `Stock` values and then use that hash as the document ID in the output section:

```
filter {
  ...
  fingerprint {
    source => ["TradeID", "Stock"]
    target => "[@metadata][id]"
  }
  ...
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
    ...
  }
}
```